# Unit testing DAO layer with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, dao

A try to test my DAO methods:

```
@Repository
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sebhaw.cms.entity"})
public class AuthoritiesDAO extends CommonClass implements IDAO<Authorities>{

    public final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthoritiesDAO.class);
    
    public EntityManager entityManager;
    
    
    @Autowired
    public AuthoritiesDAO(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    private CommonClass commonClass;
    
    static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    
    @Override
    public List<Authorities> getObjects() {
        
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query<Authorities> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Authorities",Authorities.class);
        List<Authorities> authorities = theQuery.getResultList();
        logger.warn("Query getAuthorities() on table Authorities in day: "+dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now())+" by: "+getPrincipal().toString());
        return authorities;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void saveObjects(Authorities t) {
        
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        t.setLastModifier(getPrincipal());
        logger.warn("Record saved on table Authorities in day: "+dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now())+", data: "+t.toString()+" by: "+getPrincipal().toString());
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(t);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Authorities getObjects(int theId) {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Authorities theAuthorities = currentSession.get(Authorities.class, theId);
        logger.warn("Query getAuthorities(int theId) on table Authorities in day: "
        +dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now())+"with ID: "+theId+" by: "+getPrincipal().toString());
        return theAuthorities;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void deleteEntities(int theId) {
        
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("delete from Authorities where id=:authoritiesId");
        theQuery.setParameter("authoritiesId", theId);
        logger.warn("Record deleted in table Authorities on day: "+dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now())+", with ID: "+theId+" by: "+getPrincipal().toString());
        theQuery.executeUpdate();   
    }
}
```

And this is my unit test ( not working):

```
public class AuthoritiesDAOTest {
    
    @Mock
    private Session session;
    
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    private CommonClass commonClass;
    
    private AuthoritiesDAO authoritiesDAO;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        entityManager = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
        Mockito.when(entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)).thenReturn(session);
        authoritiesDAO = new AuthoritiesDAO(entityManager);
    }
    
    @Test
    void shouldReturnEmptyCollection() {
        Query query = Mockito.mock(Query.class);
        Mockito.when(session.createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(query);
        Mockito.when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Authorities>());
        
        List<Authorities> result = authoritiesDAO.getObjects();
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

I am asking for an example of valid unit testing of my dao layer as I am in a dead end.
"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful description. Please provide the error message and stack trace, if any, or otherwise explain clearly what "not working" means in this case (i.e the behaviour you're experiencing and how it differs from what you expected). That way you wouldn't need to attach a partial Lorem Ipsum to your question. Well, "question". It's very much worded as "gimme teh code" as it is now, you might want to edit that too. Read [ask] for some tips.

Comment: My false. I have NullPointerException in line 46: ```Mockito.when(session.createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(query);```

Comment: Include that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can google it by yourself will get multiple links. some of the link

```
https://dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-dao-service-and-controller-in-spring
https://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/how-you-should-unit-test-dao-layer/
```

Comment: Do you think I am asking for Google guides or for help in the form of code, because I have exhausted all possible options from the guides?

Comment: "I am asking for an example of valid unit testing of my dao layer as I am in a dead end."
what does that mean?